# Mac can't install nvm in docker image because of certificate issues

Tags: macos, docker, ssl-certificate

In my Dockerfile I have this line for installing nvm:

```
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.3/install.sh | bash
```

And it fails with the following:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I tried the following:

- added -k option, doesn't work because the file uses another curl requests itself
- reinstalled git with brew
- added git config --global http.sslverify "false"
- export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
- installed ssl and curl with brew and linked it in my profile
- checked the clock, it's ok
- restarted the mac
- tried to clone the nvm repo and it works fine

Any other ideas? Previously, a month or 2 ago, building this image worked.

Mac version Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: does the curl fail or the script execution fail? what happens if you run that curl in isolation, could be that the script execution fails, and in that case adding -k would me meaningless

Comment: I suggest downloading the script and debugging it, start by adding a set -x at the top of the script then execute it, it should tell you where it fails

Comment: @robert.baboi curl fails itself. even if I call a non existing script on raw.githubusercontent.com it complains about ssl certificate when it should say 404

Comment: does it fail in docker only or also when you run it from your terminal?

Comment: @robert.baboi docker only, for any curl request to githubusercontent.com

Comment: hmm, feels like docker is the issue, I haven't played too much with it on mac, but I suspect it has the same issues as windows. The only thing I can suggest further is to reinstall docker on your host or wherever you are running it. But before that, maybe try to build that image on another env, like a machine on amazon or such, just to confirm that the environment is the problem and not the dockerfile. Good luck

Comment: What is the `FROM` of that container? And do you `apt` or `apk` install something in there?

Comment: You don't really need version managers in Docker images: since an image has one application and one runtime, you don't need more than one version at a time (and if you do you can easily rebuild the image).  I'd just build my image `FROM node:12` or whatever more specific version you need, and skip nvm.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.8.2

Comment: Odd, I can reproduce with a `FROM: debian` if I install curl with `--no-install-recommends`, which was what I suspected here. But since the image your are coming from [have the `ca-certificates` installed already](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/master/miniconda3/debian/Dockerfile#L7), this is working on my mac...

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I'm lost. I reinstalled docker, reinstalled local anaconda and even updated to Catalina and still the same issue.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, maybe?